# Black rectangle instead of an inductor in CircuitTikZ

Tags: circuitikz

I am trying to get an european inductor with CircuitTikZ with opposite arrows for current and voltage, but I am getting a black rectangle instead. The minimal code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[european, voltage dir = old]
\draw (0,0) to[L=$L$, v<=$\phi$,i>^=$$,] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

and the result is [image]

I am using the latest version of CircuitTikZ (hence the `\usepackage{circuitikzgit}`). I have this problem both on Windows and Ubuntu installations.

Comment: What do you expect for European inductors? Black rectangles are expected in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, to "filled rectangle" is the shape used for inductors when using the `european` flag --- (by the way, that is best specified in the global options).

But you can mix and match if you want:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[baseline, european, voltage dir = old]
\draw (0,0) to[L=$L$, v<=$\phi$,i>^=$i$,] (3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\begin{circuitikz}[baseline, european, voltage dir = old]
\ctikzset{inductor=cute}
\draw (0,0) to[L=$L$, v<=$\phi$,i>^=$i$,] (3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\begin{circuitikz}[baseline, european, voltage dir = old]
\ctikzset{inductor=american}
\draw (0,0) to[L=$L$, v<=$\phi$,i>^=$i$,] (3,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, to keep consistency, the best thing is to set this options in the preamble:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[european, oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{inductor=american}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[L=$L$, v<=$\phi$,i>^=$i$,] (3,0) to[R] ++(2,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

BTW --- do not use `$$` for an empty label. Better `\mbox{}` or (easier) `~` (a space-only label) --- `$$` works but I think it works by accident.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean "Better {}"? I tried i>^={} and it did not work.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that will trigger the "advanced" use with anchors. I adjusted the answer...